# Need suggestions with haproxy rewrite rule

Tags: url-rewriting, haproxy

I have a legacy application that need to have a rewrite rule with a new context path.

Here is the full service URL... http://localhost/myapp/myservice/api/v6/myProfile/myOffers

Above URL needs a rewrite rule to call with a different context path & most importantly ALL request headers need to be passed.

Here is what i have right now..

```
reqirep ^([^\ ]*)\ /myapp/myservice/api/v6/myProfile/myOffers \1\ /newApp/v1/myOfferList/\2
```

With the above rewrite rule, I am not able to pass the Auth headers that comes as part of the request, so result is a 401 error.

When i add `(.*)$` towards the end, something like this..

```
reqirep ^([^\ ]*)\ /myapp/myservice/api/v6/myProfile/myOffers(.*)$ \1\ /newApp/v1/myOfferList/\2
```

I am getting 405 error.

Please note that /newApp/v1/myOfferList/ supports 'POST', 'DELETE' methods.

Comment: In the last rule you listed, why is there a trailing slash at the end of `myOfferList/` but not at the end of `myOffers`?

Comment: I even tried removing it after "myOfferList" did not make any difference. I was just trying all possibilities.

Comment: Instead of the older and somewhat more delicate and less efficient `reqirep`, try `http-request set-path /newApp/v1/myOfferList if { path -m str /myapp/myservice/api/v6/myProfile/myOffers }`.  You may need something a little more sophisticated depending on whether this is just one path or a prefix but this *should* do what you want.  Mention your HAProxy version if this syntax isn't accepted.  Note that `{` and `}` must have space characterd before and after.

Comment: For some reason, my screen shows a space inside `myOffers` in the line above.  That seems to be a formatting bug on SO, obviously not supposed to be there but when I edit the comment, it's not in the original and I can't seem to edit it to make it look right.